# Printing error with python class attributes, where have I gone wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, attributes

I'm trying to print a select row and columns from a spreadsheet, however when I call on the spreadsheet dataframe attribute it fails to print state that the name dataframe is not defined. where have I gone wrong?

```
import pandas

class spreadsheet:
    def __init__(self, location, dataframe, column, rows):
        self.location = ('Readfrom.xlsx')
        self.dataframe = pandas.read_excel(location)
        self.column = 2
        self.rows = 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 27, 28, 29

a = dataframe.iloc[column,[rows]]

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instantiate an object from the Spreadsheet class and then access the attribute of the instance. You can learn more about Object-Oriented Programming in Python [here](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/).

I think that what you want to do in your code is something like the code below.

```py
import pandas

class Spreadsheet:
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location
        self.dataframe = pandas.read_excel(location)


sp = Spreadsheet(location="Readfrom.xlsx")

rows = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 27, 28, 29]

a = sp.dataframe.iloc[rows, 2]

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an indentation problem.

Your `dataframe` is a parameter of your `spreadsheet` constructor method and you try to access it even from outside the class.

To access the `dataframe` variable u have to move your code `a = dataframe.iloc[column,[rows]]` inside your `__init__` method or you need to create a `spreadsheet` object first and access it via this object.

**EDIT:**

On second thoughts i think you should check out the basics how to use classes in Python.

1. You don't use the parameters of the `__init__` so why du you have them?
2. `dataframe` is only accessible by a spreadsheet object

This code should fix your problem but i recommend to go through some basic tutorials to understand how exactly classes and objects are working:

```
import pandas

class spreadsheet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.location = ('Readfrom.xlsx')
        self.dataframe = pandas.read_excel(self.location)
        self.column = 2
        self.rows = 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 27, 28, 29

s = spreadsheet()
a = s.dataframe.iloc[s.column,[s.rows]]

print(a)
```